# Java timeout a set of instructions

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, for-loop, timeout

Is it possible to set a timeout for a set of instructions in java? I have the following:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                    //instructions
                    for(...){

                     ....
                    }
                    //instructions2
            }}).start();
```

i would like to set a timeout for the loop for and if it reaches the time continue normally with instructions2. Inside the loop i have several function calls( a litle complex organization)and can get blocked inside any one of them, resulting in long duration loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use `Thread.sleep()` or `Timer`.

Comment: The time out would not be able to unblock the blocking function calls. If you can live with that, I can imagine you indeed can stop the thread if a timeout expires/triggers.

Comment: @Crozin, how will a `Thread.sleep()` help here? (AT) OP, Are all the blocking calls interruptible? If so, setting a `Timer` before entering the loop may allow you to interrupt the calls. Else your best bet is to check the time on each iterate of the loop to see if you need to bail.

Comment: @Crozin He doesn't want to sleep, he wants to stop the for loop when a timeout expires.

Comment: @assylias: I'm sorry, I had misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your blocking functions respond to interruption, you could use a future with a timeout. If they don't there is not much you can do... Note that with the approach below you don't need to manually start the thread any more.

```
    ExecutorService forLoopExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<?> future = forLoopExecutor.submit(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //your for loop here
        }
    });
    try {
        future.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //your timeout here
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        future.cancel(true);
    }
    forLoopExecutor.shutdownNow();
    //proceed with the rest of your code
    forLoopExecutor.submit(aRunnableForInstructions2);
```

Comment: +1 If you don't want to wait for the timeout you can schedule a task to cancel the future (which does nothing if it has finished already)

Comment: This approach kind of works for me, with a few tricks. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user1812632 Just noticed that I shutdown the executor which would maket the next call to submit fail - I suppose you found out!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this example can help you

```
    long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final long TIMEOUTMILLIS = 1000;

    for(;;){

        System.out.println("bla bla bla");
        if(System.currentTimeMillis()>l+TIMEOUTMILLIS){
            break;
        }

    }
```

You can count the amount of time spent and leave the loop.

Another strategy would be to interrupt the thread after a specified amount time. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you are catching `InterruptedException` anywhere inside the for-loop, remove all of those try/catch blocks and instead have a single try/catch which surrounds the entire for-loop.  This will allow the entire for-loop to cease when you interrupt its thread.

Similarly, if you are catching `IOException`, catch `InterruptedIOException` and `ClosedByInterruptException` first.  Move those catch blocks outside of the for-loop.  (The compiler won't allow it if you are catching `IOException` internally, since there would be nothing to catch at the outer level.)

If the blocking calls are not throwing `InterruptedException`, you will need to add a check after each of them, like this:

```
if (Thread.interrupted()) {
    break;
}
```

If you have many levels of loops, you might want to add a label so you can
directly exit from that first "instructions" loop, without the need for adding
lots of flag variables:

```
instructions:
for ( ... ) {
    for ( ... ) {
        doLongOperation();
        if (Thread.interrupted()) {
            break instructions;
        }
    }
}
```

Either way, once interrupts are handled, you can have a background thread interrupt your first for-loop:

```
final Thread instructionsThread = Thread.currentThread();
Runnable interruptor = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        instructionsThread.interrupt();
    }
};
ScheduledExecutorService executor =
    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
executor.schedule(interruptor, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

// instructions
try {
    for ( ... ) {
    }
} catch (InterruptedException |
         InterruptedIOException |
         ClosedByInterruptException e) {
    logger.log(Level.FINE, "First loop timed out.", e);
} finally {
    executor.shutdown();
}

// instructions2
```